# C - pthread arguments

Tags: c, pthreads

It is the first time that I am working with threads in C and I am getting problems passing function arguments. For some reasons I need to create this thread. 
I have a function that sends a messages to a server. The header of my function is:

```
void* sender (char* payload, void (*Callback)(char*))
```

Then on my main (simplified), I create the following thread:

```
main ()
{
    pthread_t sender_id;
    int err_s;  

    err_s = pthread_create (&sender_id, NULL, &sender, NULL);
}
```

The problem is that my function sender has many arguments so I am getting this error:

```
note: expected 'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type 'void * (*)(char *, void (*)(char *))'
```

I would be gratefull if sombody could help me.

Comment: This is not possible. Every function which can be used in a thread must have the signature: void* thread_func (void* arg). I suggest you use a struct instead which contains your two arguments payload and the callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a structure lets say:

```
struct thread_prm
{
char *payload;
void (*Callback)(char*) cb;
}
```

And you just allocate a structure that looks like this and pass it to pthread_create as the last argument. Like this:

```
struct thread_prm *arg;
arg = malloc(sizeof(struct thread_prm));
(assign arg members to something)
pthread_create(&sender_id, NULL, &sender, arg);
```

And you modify sender:

```
void* sender (void *arg)
{
struct thread_prm *_arg = arg;
char* payload;
void (*Callback)(char*) cb;

payload = _arg->payload;
cb = _arg->cb;
...
}
```

Comment: If for some reason you can't modify the sender function's signature, create a wrapper function that receives this struct as void* and cast to use with sender